# Is the moderator diamond live or archived?

Tags: support, election, moderators

Okay, the question title sucks but I can't think of the right words XD

Basically what I'm asking is this: Let's say by some freak miracle I am elected a moderator. Will the moderator diamond be visible on all my previous posts and activity as a part of my profile, or will it only be shown alongside new posts and actions?

Similarly, if an existing moderator stops being one, does the diamond disappear from all their posts, even ones that they made as a moderator?

---

[Additional question](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8118071#8118071) by animuson:

> Hmmm... the thing I was curious about is do all of our past delete votes then become permanent (can't undelete things deleted by a moderator), or only the ones you actually cast as a moderator?

Comment: That's a totally separate question

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one.